# Locked voting - should we allow change after a long period of time?

Tags: discussion, comments, locked-votes, posts

I'm sure this has been asked and talked about. But this just happened:

I revisited some old question of mine. I noticed a comment and tried to upvote but was told that I already upvoted and cancelled so I can't:

> [image]

It seems with time I became smarter, so now I know that comment was helpful, but I can't do anything about it.

Same goes for voting for questions - if I change my mind after a while - say I learned something and realised he's right, or of it's in meta say I changed my mind about a topic that doesn't have a right and wrong answer - then I can't change my vote.

I understand why a vote gets "locked". But why can't we allow, say, one change every six months? It's a very specific scenario but customs, technology and opinions change. So maybe that should be allowed.

What do you think?

Comment: Making a dummy edit is always an option, especially when this situation tends to occur very rarely anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau that's true for posts, but not for comments - we can't edit comments (not even our own) and can't reverse comment upvote after a page reload even if it was mere seconds after voting.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, it's about comments? Meh, then the whole matter seems quite irrelevant in the first place. We can't downvote comments either.

Comment: @ChristianRau the first part of the question here is, yes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, that's the part I admittedly couldn't really follow at all. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau OP here is trying to discuss vote lock in general, so included both posts and comment votes - since it's just a discussion it's kind of on topic. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure, I just didn't get the part where he *"tried to upvote but was told that I already upvoted and cancelled so I can't"* - So he tried to upvote it but he already upvoted it anyway? Where's the problem then? I know what the question is about in general, all I didn't get what is actual problem with that comment upvote was (in addition to the fact that reversing comment upvotes is pretty much a non-problem anyway).

Comment: @ChristianRau yes, after you upvote a comment, you can click the arrow again to undo the upvote. Then after you reload the page, you can click the arrow again but you get this error message: http://i.stack.imgur.com/K6B3b.png and on second thought, think it's better be added to the question itself since not many people are aware of the comment un-upvote feature.

Comment: Vote lock should be completely removed. It's ineffective at preventing strategic voting, just locking it in and making it worse, and periodically annoys those of us who, upon gathering more information, realize that our votes are *wrong* and should be reversed. Vote lock only complicates the voting system and makes it less representative of the post's value.

Comment: @ChristianRau I know it's a minor issue but I'd argue that everything on meta these days is mostly minor things. Also, the votes you got for your first comment on a dummy edit prove that the need for this isn't so rare as you'd think

Comment: @yuvi *"the votes you got for your first comment on a dummy edit prove that this isn't so rare as you'd think"* - Can't follow that logic, though. But nevermind.

Comment: @ChristianRau I'm saying I think a lot of people use that workaround (I do that too sometimes) but that's still a workaround

Comment: This is very reasonable feature-request. My main concern with allowing users to re-vote on posts again without editing is that rage-quitting users could go to all the posts they upvoted and switch them to downvotes. Sure, this is still pretty rare to ever happen but there have been confirmed cases of rage-quitters unaccepting all the answers they previously accepted. The difference is that the community can not easily tell this (maybe in SEDE though). But limiting this to like 5 changes or some smallish number every month or 6 months is definitely a great compromise.

Comment: @CRABOLO as far as I know there are scripts intended to detect that sort of thing (and there's nothing stopping rage-quitters from downvoting things they haven't voted on before), but yeah limiting it a bit will solve that